# How Clear Back Stack on Xamarin IOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

When a user authenticates correctly, it will be directed to the **HomeViewModel**. I want to remove the possibility that it can return to the login screen so I have created a **Custom Presenter** to remove all the screens that are below the new screen.

The implementation is as follows:

```
 public class CustomPresenter: MvxFormsIosPagePresenter
    {
        public CustomPresenter(UIWindow window, MvxFormsApplication mvxFormsApp)
         : base(window, mvxFormsApp)
        {
        }

        public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
        {

            if (request.PresentationValues?["NavigationCommand"] == "StackClear")
            {
                var navigation = FormsApplication.MainPage.Navigation;
                Debug.WriteLine("Navigation Back Stack Count -> " + navigation.NavigationStack.Count());
                navigation.PopToRootAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine("Navigation Back Stack Count After PopToRootAsync -> " + navigation.NavigationStack.Count());
                return;
            }

            base.Show(request);
        }
    }
```

When the authentication process finishes correctly, I navigate to the home screen by passing a bundle with this special command:

```
LoginWithFacebookCommand.Subscribe(token => {
                Debug.WriteLine("JWT Token -> " + token);
                _userDialogs.ShowSuccess(AppResources.Login_Success);
                var mvxBundle = new MvxBundle(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "NavigationCommand", "StackClear" } });
                ShowViewModel<HomeViewModel>(presentationBundle: mvxBundle);
            });
```

The problem is that it does not change the screen, it stays in the current one. What would be the way to do it correctly ?.

I am using **MvvmCross 5.1.1** and **MvvmCross.Forms 5.1.1**

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Alternatively, you could launch you home screen, check if the users is authenticated, and push a modal with your login form if they need to sign in. I've used Mvvm Frameworks like Prism, which makes manipulating the navigation stack easy, but I am not sure how simple it is in MvvmCross.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, `PopToRootAsync()` pops everything off the stack to the root. Which means you should then push your view that you wish to navigate to, onto your stack after that method is called i.e. use `PushViewController(yourViewController)` afterwards. Also, you should be using the new `IMvxNavigationService` by MvvmCross. You can give this a try:

```
var navigationService = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxNavigationService>();

LoginWithFacebookCommand.Subscribe(async (token) => {
                Debug.WriteLine("JWT Token -> " + token);

                _userDialogs.ShowSuccess(AppResources.Login_Success);

                await navigationService.Navigate<HomeViewModel>();
            });
```

To clear the backstack you basically need to override the Show method in the presenter and check whether your viewmodel is being called. If it is then set a new array of viewControllers. (**Credit to @pnavk!!**)

```
public class CustomPresenter : MvxIosViewPresenter
    {
        public override void Show(IMvxIosView view, MvxViewModelRequest request)
        {
            if (MasterNavigationController != null && view.ViewModel.GetType() == typeof(HomeViewModel))
            {
                var viewController = view as UIViewController;
                MasterNavigationController.SetViewControllers(new UIViewController[] { viewController }, true);
            }
            else
                base.Show(view, request);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
navigation.SetViewControllers(new UIViewController[] { vc }, true);
```

vc is the ViewController you want to set as the root of the navigation stack. You will need to get a reference to it which you can using the ViewControllers property on the NavigationController.

true - means you want to animate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. FormsApplication.MainPage.Navigation does not have this method. Could you explain how I can apply it in my example?

Comment: @SergioSánchezSánchez, pnavk's solution is for use within the Presenter and references the UIKit package. UIKit.UINavigationController.SetViewControllers. I'm using MvvmCross with Xamarin and not Xamarin Forms so I don't know whether this applies to Forms as well.

Comment: @SergioSánchezSánchez sorry just read now that you are also using MvvmCross :). I'm also looking for a solution to this and giving pnavk's solution a try (busy debugging as I type :P ). I'll post a more detailed answer if I come right.